# actix-web json unexpected behavior

Tags: rust, actix-web

I was playing around with actix-web and ran into the following issue.
I have 2 functions and one function takes post string request and returns a json of a struct and the other takes json of struct and returns string. However, taking json struct gives error 400.

Struct code

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct MyObj {
    pub name: String,
}
```

functions

```
#[post("/simple")]
pub async fn simple(obj: String) -> impl Responder {
    MyObj {
        name: obj,
    }
}

#[post("/simplerecv")]
pub async fn simplerrecv(_obj: web::Json<MyObj>) -> String {
    println!("Inside simplerecv");
    "Hello".to_owned()
}
```

Python code used to test this

```
def simple():
    # testing simple
    data = "hello44444"
    r1 = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/simple", data=json.dumps(data))
    print(r1.status_code, type(r1.text), r1.text)
    res = json.loads(r1.text)
    r2 = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/simplerecv",
                       data=json.dumps(json.loads(r1.text)))
    print(r2.status_code)
```

Output of Python code

200 <class 'str'> {"name":""hello44444""} 
400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some web servers don't accept JSON without `Content-Type: application/json`, and so does actix-web.

```py
r2 = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/simplerecv",
                   headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
                   data=json.dumps(json.loads(r1.text)))
```

Comment: Including `;charset=utf-8` is neither necessary (when communicating with standards-conforming systems) nor correct — the specification for the `application/json` type _does not define_ a `charset` parameter, and specifies that the encoding is UTF-8. (It might necessary in practice due to specific nonconformant implementations which don't decode as UTF-8, as they should, unless specifically told to, though — but there's no reason to include it if you're not sending the request to such a nonconformant web server.)